# Insert new table row after displaying X elements

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have an array containing the URLs for a number of different images.

My aim is to output the first seven images in the array, create a new line, output the next 7 images, create a new line, and continue doing this until there are no more URLs left inside the array.

**Current Code**

```
<?php
            $command = 'select * from products;';//The command to be executed
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $command); //The result of the command
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
                {
                    // output data of each row
                    echo "<table align='center'>";
                    $images = array();
                    $name = array();
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) //Store all product images and their names in two SEPERATE arrays
                        {
                            $images[] = $row['Image'];
                            $names[] = $row['Name'];
                        }
                    for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++)
                        {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        foreach($images as $image)
                            {
                                echo "<td> <img src='" . $image . "' height='80' width='100'/></td>";
                            }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }   
                }
        ?>
```

At the moment, this code outputs all of the images inside the `$images[]` array horizontally but does NOT create a new line after the first seven images are displayed.

I'm placing the images inside a table so that the output is evenly spaced.

Can someone point me in the right direction in order to have my desired output? I've looked around and attempted several solutions, but I'm no further forward.

Comment: can i break your code for building a new code?

Comment: @FrayneKonok Sure.

Comment: checkout the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this line of code:**

I did without the table, cause i don't see any advantage of the table here. If you want to make things clear then use the `CSS`.

```
<?php
$command = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $command); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  $i = 1;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
  if($i++ > 6) echo "<br/>";?>
    <img src="<?php echo $row->Image;?>" height='80' width='100'/>
  <?php }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to store the number of items you want per line, and check that you reach this number before closing the line :

```
$nbImagesPerRow = 7;
```

Getting how many images you got :

```
$nbImages = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Instanciate two variables, one that checks the current row and the other to check when the table ends :

```
$currentRowImageIndex = 1;
$totalImageIndex = 1;
```

Then, when you loop, you check wether you must open or close a new line :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (1 === $currentRowImageIndex) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    ...

    if (
        $currentRowImageIndex >= $nbImagesPerRow
        || $totalImageIndex >= $nbImages) {
        $currentRowImageIndex = 1;
        // you also should deal with the last line colspan when $totalImageIndex >= $nbImages)
        echo '<tr>';
    } else {
        $currentRowImageIndex++;
    }
$totalImageIndex++;
```

Don't hesitate to use an html grid system such as Bootstraps' or foundations' (many more exist) that allows you to align elements horizontally in divs and adapt to the user screen.